# Existence of maximal chordal graphs

Tags: graph-theory, chordal-graphs

A [chordal graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_graph) is one in which all cycles of four or more vertices have a chord, which is an edge that is not part of the cycle but connects two vertices of the cycle.

I'm not sure whether the concept of **maximal chordal graphs** exists. I tentatively define it as follows:

- A chordal graph is *maximal*  if adding an edge between any two non-adjacent vertices makes the graph non-chordal or non-simple.

According to the definition, complete graphs meet the requirements, but are there any others besides complete graphs?

Sometimes induced cycles that are not triangles are called "**holes**".  That is to say, adding any edge will create a hole. Do such chordal graphs (but not complete graphs) exist?

**Note:** If such non-complete chordal graphs do not exist, then starting from any chordal graph, we can continually add edges (while maintaining its chordal property) until it becomes a complete graph.

I tested chordal graphs with at most 10 vertices one by one using a computer and did not find a desired maximal chordal graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complete graphs are the only chordal graphs with the property that adding any non-edge creates a hole.

Let $G$ be such a graph. Let $k \geq 0$ be the largest so that there exists $x, y, z_1, \dots, z_k \in V(G)$ forming an induced $K_{k+2}-e$ in $G$ with $xy$ as the missing edge. Since $xy$ is a non-edge, adding $xy$ would create a hole $x w_1 \dots w_\ell y$ with $\ell \geq 2$. Notice that the $w_i$ are distinct from the $z_i$, as otherwise there would be a chord in this hole. Since $x w_1 \dots w_\ell y z_i$ is a cycle in $G$, but there are no edges among $x, w_1, \dots w_\ell, y$ other than those in the cycle, we have that every $z_i$ is adjacent to every $w_j$. Since $x$ is not adjacent to $w_2$, we have that $x, w_2, z_1, \dots, z_k, w_1$ forms an induced $K_{k+3}-e$ with $xw_2$ as the missing edge, contradicting the maximality of $k$.

Thus $G$ has no induced $K_2-e$, that is, every pair of vertices in $G$ are adjacent.